# Segmentation fault when using strlen on user input string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strlen

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with my code. 
I have a string composed by words inserted by user input. 
I've terminated the string so it should be ok.

Then I use another cycle to reverse the direction of the words. But when I call STRLEN on the last word of the string, it gives me segmentation fault. 
(the reversal part is not done yet, since i'm stuck with this problem).

Why?

Here is the code:

```
char *frase, c;
int i=0;
int d=1; 
frase = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); 

printf("Insert phrase: ");
while(c != '\n') { 
    c = getc(stdin);     
    frase = (char*)realloc(frase,d*sizeof(char)); //dynamic allocation
    frase[i] = c;
    d++;
    i++;
}

//at the end i terminate the string
frase[i]='\0';
printf("\nInserted phrase: %s\n",frase);

// here I start the reversal, first of all I separate all the words
char *pch;
char s[2] = " ";
int messl=0;

pch = strtok (frase,s);
printf ("%s\n",pch);
messl += 1 + strlen(pch);
printf ("Lung stringa = %d\n",messl);
char *message = (char*) malloc(messl);

while (pch != NULL) {
    pch = strtok (NULL, s);
    printf("%s\n",pch);
    messl += 1 + strlen(pch); //in the last cycle of the loop I get the error

}
//printf ("%s\n",message);
return 0;
```

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: `while(c != '\n')`...UB at first run.

Comment: `messl += 1 + strlen(pch);`...is it real?

Comment: `frase[i]='\0';` writes past the end of the `realloc`'d space

Comment: thank you for the advices, I'll fix the errors!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code.

```
 while(c != '\n')
```

at the very first iteration, `c` is uninitialised. It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to use the value of an automatic local variable which has not been initialized explicitly.

[`getc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) returns an `int` which , at times, may not *fit* into a `char`. Change the type of `c`  to `int`.

That said, as you mentioned in your question, that you're getting segfault from `strlen()`, you need check for the non-NULL value of the passed pointer to `strlen()`. Add the NULL-check to `pch` immediately after tokenizing.

Comment: @user3318528 You're welcome . :-) BTW, you can consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) an answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is:

```
while (pch != NULL) {
    pch = strtok (NULL, s);
    printf("%s\n",pch);
    messl += 1 + strlen(pch);
```

When `strtok` returns `NULL`, you go on to call `printf` and `strlen` on it.  You need to immediately test `pch` upon calling `strtok`. For example the loop structure could be:

```
while ( (pch = strtok(NULL, s)) != NULL ) {
```

---

There are various other problems too, as other answerers/commentors have noted.